How to get backgound-color working on a row - html and CSS
I get get the background color to work on a <td> but not a <tr>.
I am using Firefox, version: 128.0+linuxmint1+virginia  on Linux Mint (Mate)


body {
  margins: 2mm;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif
}

p {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0.0in
}

table {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

table tr.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

table th {
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

table td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

table td.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}
<P> $Revision$</p>
<br>

<table class="sample" width="98%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <col width="18%">
  <col width="12%">
  <col width="12%">
  <col width="12%">
  <col width="12%">
  <col width="12%">
  <col width="12%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>AM</th>
      <th>PM</th>
      <th>AM</th>
      <th>PM</th>
      <th>AM</th>
      <th>PM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="yellow">
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td class="aqua">&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
    <td>&emsp;</td>

  </tr>
</table>



Resulting Firefox display:
The 'aqua' colored <td> works.
The 'yellow' colored <tr> does not work!! ( remains black characters on white background.

I am not interested in striping.
I realize that I could set each <td> in the row, but I would like to know why the <tr> property does not work.
I did read the similar question where an extra space ruined the grammar.
Running tidy returned "No warnings or errors were found.

I edited the code in your question to become a running code snippet, and as far as I can tell your posted code works. While I did strip the HTML down to the contents of the <body> element, and moved the CSS into the CSS pane (out of the document's <head> and <style> elements), I didn't edit or change the code itself.

Cannot reproduce in FF Nightly

Did you make sure that td elements do not inherit a white background from somewhere else in your CSS? The code above works for me as expected in chrome and firefox.
